# why the git bash in windows shows could not fork child process?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

The problem is that when i open a git bash terminal, it shows me that : "could not fork a child process, there is no available terminal." I have tried to restart the terminal, but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-bash%5D+could+not+fork+child+process%2C+there+are+no+available+terminals